# jQuery in DELPHI win32

Tags: jquery, delphi

Is it possible to use jQuery in win32 application?

I have seen interesting stuff made with jQuery, I like to know if it is possible to use it in win32 applications.

Like so many others I do not want to switch to .NET or the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is not supported in the 32-bit compiler for Delphi.

However, jQuery can be used with [IntraWeb](http://www.atozed.com/IntraWeb/index.EN.aspx) which can in turned be used with Delphi to create web applications, but not win32 applications. IntraWeb allows you to develop VCL Forms applications using Delphi but deploy to the web as standard HTML and JavaScript.

IntraWeb is included with the Delphi XE installer package.

Comment: Using IntraWeb you're developing WEB applications, not Win32 applications.

Comment: Good point, it was not explicitly clear. I have updated my answer to make it clear that jQuery is not supported in win32 desktop development for Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a JavaScript library and most of its features have high dependency on (X)HTML DOM. That's you can use JavaScript embedding some JavaScript interpreter, but what would jQuery manipulate?

If you're looking for a rapid application development with high quality graphics and animations support, and XML-based UI composition, you definitively need to look forward to .NET/WPF (it seems you don't like Microsoft solutions, but you're missing one of best UI frameworks - Windows Presentation Foundation and Silverlight), Adobe Air/Flex, JavaFX, Mozilla XUL...

Comment: There's no jQuery for WPF either.

Comment: Haha, but you know I'm not talking about jQuery in WPF. I'm talking about if he wants such things, he needs to look forward for that other technologies.

Comment: XPath can be considered an alternative to JQuery selectors in most XML-based presentation languages such as XAML, see examples here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0f8b4dc5-b6e8-40c1-a0b4-11786fa6c26f

Comment: ías, so it reads like this: Q: "How do I use jQuery with Delphi?". A: "You use XPath with WPF". Errr. The first paragraph of your answer is perfect, I'd vote for it, but the second paragraph is an answer to a different question.

Comment: Hey, double-check how starts the second paragraph: "If you're looking for a rapid [...]". I'm suggesting he's in the wrong way and he can't expect jQuery outside Web development. Correct me if you didn't understand that, I can try to compose it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a TWebBrowser or [Google's Compact Embeddable Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) into your Delphi application, then load and execute JQuery either from files or resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delphi TWebbrowse component to load an html containing some jquery modules loaded from local path.